# Using grep to search for multiple keywords on different lines

Tags: bash, command-line, grep, pipe, file-search

I'm completing a command line game/challenge that involves solving a murder mystery.

One of the steps is to search for a suspect by using grep to search for multiple keywords in one file.

However that file contains thousands of lines of text that has the following format:

```
License Plate: L337ZR9
Make: Honda
Color: Red
Owner: Katie Park
Height: 6'2"
```

I have tried using grep in the following ways:

```
cat vehicles | grep -i 'L337' | grep -i 'honda'
ls | grep -i 'honda\|blue\|L337'
```

But as i understand it these commands will give me any result that matches any one of my three search terms.

What command do i need to search the vehicle file and display matches only match for Blue Honda with license plate of L337 - in other words what command allows grep to find and display results of multiple matching search terms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use *GNU* `grep`.

**Example**

*Source*

```
License Plate: L337ZR9
Make: Honda
Color: Blue
Owner: Katie Park
Height: 6'2"
License Plate: L338ZR9
Make: Honda
Color: Black
Owner: James Park
Height: 6'0"
```

*Command*

```
grep -Pzo '\w+:\s*L337ZR9\n\w+:\s+Honda\n\w+:\s*Blue' file
```

*Result*

```
Plate: L337ZR9
Make: Honda
Color: Blue
```

**Explanation**

From `grep` man:

> ```
>    -z, --null-data
>           Treat the input as a set of lines,
> ```

**NOTE**: `grep (GNU grep) 2.20` *tested*

Answer (score 1):

First realize that you are `grep`ping records, not lines.

So merge the 5 line records into a single line:

```
cat licenseplates | paste - - - - -
```

Now it is suddenly easy to `grep`:

```
cat licenseplates | paste - - - - - |
  grep -i 'L337' | grep -i 'honda' | grep -i blue
```

Finally you need to fold the matching lines back into 5 line records:

```
cat licenseplates | paste - - - - - |
  grep -i 'L337' | grep -i 'honda' | grep -i blue |
  sed 's/\t/\n/g'
```